# Bitcoin Transaction never confirmed even with a significant fee?

Tags: confirmations, zero-confirmation

I just had some questions in regards to relating fee/byte to confirmation. From an exchange the withdrawal fee for bitcoin is fixed to 0.0005 btc but the bytes vary very much, and thus you get very different fees/byte.
Transaction id [eb956503c6459d564cb097064f6093a14d85a607f7dca76d265a21d90eeecb7f](https://blockchain.info/tx/eb956503c6459d564cb097064f6093a14d85a607f7dca76d265a21d90eeecb7f)
and for some strange reason this transaction can only be viewed on https://blockchain.info and not the other block chain explorer's I tried to use. It has a 61.2 sat/B fee/Byte, over 5 days later it has not reached a single confirmation.

According to https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/ the max time I should of waited for 61.2 sat/B is 1200 minutes or 20 hours, which I'm well way above.

I tried sending a larger amount of bitcoin to the same address manually with a massive fee/byte in the hopes that the 61.2 sat/Byte fee transaction would get a confirmation, but it didn't, only that one did (I read somewhere that by doing this it could confirm the slower one).

I didn't want to have to waste someones time with this, but the question is if it's possible that an error or glitch may have happened between the blockchain or miners that could of caused this? Considering the future time valuation of a risky asset like bitcoin, then it can be thought that the longer I wait for this, the more intrinsic value I lose.

Comment: https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/ is highly inaccurate, have a look at https://core.jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h. Currently around 350 S/B TX are getting confirmed

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the possible duplicate, it was not my intention